# Google Cloud WP Install Issue "ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","

Tags: google-cloud-platform, runtime-error

wordpress-1 has resource level errors
wordpress-1-software: {"ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","ResourceErrorMessage":"Timeout expired."}

Here is the SS: https://prnt.sc/bMVDQ46TgdIv

Try to too many solution but not solved.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the Wordpress Click to Deploy by Google? Also, which region are you trying to deploy to?

Comment: WordPress Certified by Bitnami and Automattic. Now i am using usa-central-1.

Comment: {"ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","ResourceErrorMessage":"Timeout expired."} may also relate to the resource unavailability on the said region, If you are seeing a ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED from the Activity Logs.
What kind of machine type were you trying to deploy? Were you also able to try to deploy in a different region?

Comment: I am also getting the following error, I tried deploying in `us-east1-b` and it shows the same error